# date and replace method only change the first found value

Tags: javascript, replace

I m trying to replace some values from a date but it only change the first found value.

```
var date= cars.getAttribute("myLastDate");
var dateChanged= date.replace("/", ",");
alert (dateChanged);
```

Best regards.

Comment: can you put your html code part?

Comment: MDN is a really good reference on usage of JS functions like [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), and on JS in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to invoke the *global* flag using a *regular expression*:

```
var dateChanged= date.replace(/\//g, ",");
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need any regular expressions then I recommend the simpler split/join method to do search and replace.

```
var dateChanged = date.split("/").join(",");
```

Answer (score 1):

replace in javascript use regular expression , u have to add /g at the end

```
date.replace(text/g,' ')
```